# how can I blink flashlight of iphone on local / Remote notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I was not able to find the code to blink the flashlight as it blinks in the Android if any notification comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*all you have to call this function:*

/////////////

```
- (void)torchOnOff: (BOOL) onOff
{

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device hasTorch]) {

    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    [device setTorchMode: onOff ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by pointing out that not all Android devices have a front or back LED for notifications. With that said, by default, Android devices do not turn on the flash for notifications. Some devices do have a notification LED such as the latest Samsung Galaxy models. These devices do not use the camera flashlight for notification by default for a good reason...it is annoying and it sucks more power from the battery.

iPhones donot have a notification LED, however, you can turn on the flash LED from the phone Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> LED Flash for Alerts

So basically, it is a built-in accessibility feature. However, if you want to make your app blink the camera Flash LED you will need to get the default capture device with the help of [`AVCaptureDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

Then create a session and start the session. I added a link where you will find all the information necessary on how to configure the session
Good Luck!